# ReadOnlySequence.GetPosition returns wrong position

Tags: c#, .net

I'm using the .NET Standard 2.1 Preview 8. I build a small program that essentially writes/reads from a TcpSocket. The reading is done with `Pipe`.

Given the following implementation

```cs
var pipe = new Pipe();

await pipe.Writer.WriteAsync(new ReadOnlyMemory<byte>(new byte[100]));
await pipe.Writer.FlushAsync();

while (true)
{
    var readResult = await pipe.Reader.ReadAsync();
    if (readResult.Buffer.Length <= 0)
        break;

    Console.WriteLine("Buffer length:" + readResult.Buffer.Length);
    Console.WriteLine("Buffer start:" + readResult.Buffer.Start.GetInteger());

    var position = readResult.Buffer.GetPosition(10);
    Console.WriteLine("End position:" + position.GetInteger());
    Console.WriteLine();

    pipe.Reader.AdvanceTo(position);
}
```

This scenario writes 100 bytes to the `PipeWriter`. Then in the loop the buffer is read and the Reader advances by 10 bytes.

This generates the following output:

```
Buffer length:100
Buffer start:0
End position:10

Buffer length:90
Buffer start:10
End position:20

Buffer length:80
Buffer start:20
End position:30

Buffer length:70
Buffer start:30
End position:40

Buffer length:60
Buffer start:40
End position:50

Buffer length:50
Buffer start:50
End position:60

Buffer length:40
Buffer start:60
End position:70

Buffer length:30
Buffer start:70
End position:80

Buffer length:20
Buffer start:80
End position:90

Buffer length:10
Buffer start:90
End position:100
```

I don't understand why the buffer start and the position advances by 10 every iteration. I would expect after a read on a pipe that for every iteration the buffer start is 0 and when I get the position with a offset of 10 the position would be 10. Only the buffer size should decrease by 10 every iteration.

Is there a bug or is position defined in an other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out that `SequencePosition.GetInteger()` is considered for internal use. Using a `SequenceReader` (as proposed [here](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/40679)) did the trick for me.

As `SequenceReader` is not available in Standard I filled this [issue](https://github.com/dotnet/standard/issues/1493).